# How to fix the error "the flink application failed to deploy on yarn"

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

The following is the error message snapshot.
[image: the error message]

Comment: Can you provide more information please ? In which moment it happens, what conf you have, what you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing max open files would fix the issue.